# How to adjust a variable via dividing it by the sum of observations in previous days?

Tags: date, sas, statistics, formula, volume

I want to write a code to run the formula which is shown below:

Adjusted volume for each name and date = IntradayVolume / ( dailyvolume for five last days)

And I use codes which are shown below:

```
*Division for calculating adjusted volume;
proc sort data=sampledata_sumvolso02 out=sampledata_sumvolso02;
by TRD_STCK_CD TRD_EVENT_DT;
run;

*Adjusted intraday volume for days of a week;
data sampledata_adjvol02;
     do until(last.TRD_STCK_CD);
           do until(last.TRD_EVENT_DT);
                set sampledata_sumvolso02;
                by TRD_STCK_CD TRD_EVENT_DT;

                if first.TRD_STCK_CD then
                     n=0;

                if first.TRD_EVENT_DT then
                     n+1;

                if n>7 then
                     do;
                           if not missing(IntradayVolume) then
                                adjusted_volume=divide(IntradayVolume,temp);
                                else call missing(adjusted_volume);
                     end;

                if last.TRD_EVENT_DT then
                     temp=dailyvolume;
                output;
           end;
     end;
     drop temp n;
run;
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
data WORK.SAMPLEDATA_SUMVOLSO02;
  infile datalines dsd truncover;
  input TRD_STCK_CD:$15. TRD_PR:32. TRD_TUROVR:14. TRD_EVENT_DT:DATE9. TRD_EVENT_TM:TIME5. TRD_EVENT_ROUNDED:32. TRD_EVENT_ROUFOR:$5. CountedVOLUME:32. DailyVolume:32. IntradayVolume:32.;
  format TRD_TUROVR 14. TRD_EVENT_DT DATE9. TRD_EVENT_TM TIME5.;
  label TRD_STCK_CD="TRD_STCK_CD" TRD_PR="TRD_PR" TRD_TUROVR="TRD_TUROVR" TRD_EVENT_DT="TRD_EVENT_DT";
datalines4;
BALI1,850,9260,24MAR2008,9:14,34200,9:30,7871000,,
BALI1,850,2000,23MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,1700000,,
BALI1,850,10000,22MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,8500000,,
BALI1,850,6000,21MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,5100000,,
BALI1,850,10000,20MAR2008,9:29,34200,9:30,8500000,31671000,31671000
BANK1,1164,10729,20MAR2008,9:38,36000,10:00,12488556,,12488556
BANK1,1148,2000,21MAR2008,11:24,41400,11:30,2296000,,
BANK1,1147,1575,22MAR2008,11:24,41400,11:30,1806525,16591081,4102525
BHMN1,1013,1500,14MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,15MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,16MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,17MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,18MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,19MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1000,20MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1013000,,
BHMN1,1013,450,21MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,455850,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,22MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,23MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,24MAR2008,9:04,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,25MAR2008,9:04,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,601,26MAR2008,9:05,34200,9:30,608813,,
BHMN1,1013,697,27MAR2008,9:06,34200,9:30,706061,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,28MAR2008,9:08,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,29MAR2008,9:08,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,12MAR2008,9:09,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,13MAR2008,9:16,34200,9:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,14MAR2008,9:22,34200,9:30,1519500,,25576224
BHMN1,1013,1500,15MAR2008,9:41,36000,10:00,1519500,,1519500
BHMN1,1013,1500,16MAR2008,10:13,37800,10:30,1519500,,
BHMN1,1013,1500,17MAR2008,10:13,37800,10:30,1519500,,3039000
BHMN1,1013,1500,18MAR2008,11:25,41400,11:30,1519500,,1519500
BHMN1,1013,1500,19MAR2008,11:51,43200,12:00,1519500,33173724,1519500
CHML1,12000,745,20MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,8940000,,
CHML1,12000,82,21MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,984000,,
CHML1,11998,206,22MAR2008,9:07,34200,9:30,2471588,,
CHML1,11998,414,23MAR2008,9:09,34200,9:30,4967172,,
CHML1,11998,348,24MAR2008,9:12,34200,9:30,4175304,,
CHML1,11996,82,25MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,983672,,
CHML1,11996,1240,26MAR2008,9:16,34200,9:30,14875040,,
CHML1,11996,414,27MAR2008,9:17,34200,9:30,4966344,,
CHML1,11970,1000,28MAR2008,9:21,34200,9:30,11970000,,
CHML1,11964,158,29MAR2008,9:22,34200,9:30,1890312,,
CHML1,11990,1946,20MAR2008,9:23,34200,9:30,23332540,,79555972
CHML1,11851,500,19MAR2008,10:42,39600,11:00,5925500,,
CHML1,11852,1054,18MAR2008,10:44,39600,11:00,12492008,,
CHML1,11900,2000,17MAR2008,10:56,39600,11:00,23800000,,42217508
CHML1,11913,244,16MAR2008,11:08,41400,11:30,2906772,,
CHML1,11913,56,15MAR2008,11:09,41400,11:30,667128,,
CHML1,11968,944,14MAR2008,11:13,41400,11:30,11297792,,
CHML1,11968,2056,13MAR2008,11:27,41400,11:30,24606208,,
CHML1,11987,380,14MAR2008,11:29,41400,11:30,4555060,,44032960
CHML1,11988,620,11MAR2008,11:30,43200,12:00,7432560,,
CHML1,11981,1663,12MAR2008,11:52,43200,12:00,19924403,,
CHML1,11981,765,24MAR2008,11:52,43200,12:00,9165465,202328868,36522428
CRBN1,1486,1700,22MAR2008,9:00,34200,9:30,2526200,,
CRBN1,1485,3353,24MAR2008,9:21,34200,9:30,4979205,7505405,7505405
DADE1,1685,2972,24MAR2008,10:04,37800,10:30,5007820,,5007820
DADE1,1632,2000,20MAR2008,11:49,43200,12:00,3264000,,
DADE1,1631,5000,21MAR2008,11:49,43200,12:00,8155000,,
DADE1,1630,3000,22MAR2008,11:49,43200,12:00,4890000,,
DADE1,1630,2000,23MAR2008,11:50,43200,12:00,3260000,,
DADE1,1630,8000,24MAR2008,11:50,43200,12:00,13040000,37616820,32609000
DFRB1,7450,124,24MAR2008,10:54,39600,11:00,923800,,923800
DFRB1,7450,132,24MAR2008,11:16,41400,11:30,983400,1907200,983400
DJBR1,7491,3000,24MAR2008,10:06,37800,10:30,22473000,22473000,22473000
DRZK1,14890,72,24MAR2008,11:58,43200,12:00,1072080,1072080,1072080
FIBR1,2846,100,24MAR2008,11:17,41400,11:30,284600,284600,284600
FKAS1,3584,5173,20MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,18540032,,
FKAS1,3584,3000,21MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,10752000,,
FKAS1,3585,1827,22MAR2008,9:15,34200,9:30,6549795,,35841827
FKAS1,3585,183,23MAR2008,9:35,36000,10:00,656055,,
FKAS1,3585,3200,24MAR2008,9:35,36000,10:00,11472000,,12128055
FKAS1,3539,2000,25MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,7078000,,
FKAS1,3538,8000,26MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,28304000,,
FKAS1,3538,2000,27MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,7076000,,
FKAS1,3537,8000,28MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,28296000,,
FKAS1,3537,2000,29MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,7074000,,
FKAS1,3535,8000,20MAR2008,11:02,41400,11:30,28280000,,
FKAS1,3535,2000,19MAR2008,11:03,41400,11:30,7070000,,
FKAS1,3535,6617,18MAR2008,11:03,41400,11:30,23391095,,
FKAS1,3533,100,17MAR2008,11:03,41400,11:30,353300,,
FKAS1,3533,1283,16MAR2008,11:07,41400,11:30,4532839,,
FKAS1,3533,2763,15MAR2008,11:08,41400,11:30,9761679,,
FKAS1,3529,10000,14MAR2008,11:15,41400,11:30,35290000,,
FKAS1,3516,10000,13MAR2008,11:17,41400,11:30,35160000,,
FKAS1,3516,10000,12MAR2008,11:19,41400,11:30,35160000,,
FKAS1,3516,39,11MAR2008,11:19,41400,11:30,137124,,
FKAS1,3515,2000,19MAR2008,11:25,41400,11:30,7030000,,
FKAS1,3515,198,24MAR2008,11:25,41400,11:30,695970,,
FKAS1,3515,9802,20MAR2008,11:25,41400,11:30,34454030,,299144037
FKAS1,3515,4000,21MAR2008,11:48,43200,12:00,14060000,,
FKAS1,3513,6000,22MAR2008,11:52,43200,12:00,21078000,,
FKAS1,3514,2000,23MAR2008,11:52,43200,12:00,7028000,,
FKAS1,3514,1085,24MAR2008,11:52,43200,12:00,3812690,,
FKAS1,3500,1000,25MAR2008,11:56,43200,12:00,3500000,396592609,49478690
FOLD1,3198,390,24MAR2008,9:09,34200,9:30,1247220,,1247220
FOLD1,3197,2000,27MAR2008,10:31,39600,11:00,6394000,,
FOLD1,3191,2000,28MAR2008,10:32,39600,11:00,6382000,,
FOLD1,3190,4000,20MAR2008,10:33,39600,11:00,12760000,,
FOLD1,3190,542,18MAR2008,10:33,39600,11:00,1728980,,
;;;;
```

Now, I want to divide Intradayvolume variable by aggregated  Dailyvolume variable in a week before today. It is important to specify for SAS to diagnoses days of a week and adapts it with the date variable in my dataset. Because the format of the date variable of my dataset is ddmmyy. I mean SAS should find which days of a week are today and aggregates Dailyvolume variable of a week before today as the denominator.

How can I run that formula?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a solution for this question:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699911/how-can-i-calculate-the-division-using-sas/45709253#45709253)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data sampledata_adjvol (drop=cnt dv_:);
    set Sampledata_SumVolSo;
    by TRD_STCK_CD TRD_EVENT_DT;
    retain dv_1 dv_2 dv_3 dv_4 cnt 0 dv_sum;
    if first.TRD_STCK_CD then do;
        cnt=0;
        dv_1=0;
        dv_2=0;
        dv_3=0;
        dv_4=0;
        dv_sum=0;
    end;
        adjusted_volume_5=intradayvolume/dv_sum;
    if last.TRD_EVENT_DT then do;
        cnt=cnt+1;
        if cnt=1 then dv_4=dailyvolume;
        else if cnt=2 then dv_3=dailyvolume;
        else if cnt=3 then dv_2=dailyvolume;
        else if cnt=4 then dv_1=dailyvolume;
        else do;
            dv_sum=dailyvolume+dv_1+dv_2+dv_3+dv_4;
            dv_4=dv_3;
            dv_3=dv_2;
            dv_2=dv_1;
            dv_1=dailyvolume;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing there, but one approach might be to create a temporary array and index it with the date.  Then look up in that index.  You'd have some issues with that simplistic of a method with holidays and such, but it should give you at least an approximately right answer.

For example (again, I don't entirely understand your variables or what you're doing, so this is an approximate idea):

```
*Adjusted intraday volume for days of a week;
data sampledata_adjvol02;
     array prevdat[32767] _temporary_;
     do until(last.TRD_STCK_CD);
           do until(last.TRD_EVENT_DT);
                set sampledata_sumvolso02;
                by TRD_STCK_CD TRD_EVENT_DT;

                if first.TRD_STCK_CD then
                     n=0;

                if first.TRD_EVENT_DT then
                     n+1;

                if n>7 then
                     do;
                           if not missing(IntradayVolume) then
                                adjusted_volume=divide(IntradayVolume,prevdat[TRD_EVENT_DT-7]);
                                else call missing(adjusted_volume);
                     end;

                if last.TRD_EVENT_DT then
                     temp=dailyvolume;
                output;
                prevdat[TRD_EVENT_DT] = sum(prevdat[TRD_EVENT_DT],countedVolume);
           end;

     end;

     call missing(of prevdat[*]);
     drop temp n;
run;
```

Comment: What is 32767 mean?

Comment: @AminKarimi 32767 refers to number of cells in the array.