# How can I calculate the division using SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics

I want to calculate adjusted_volume variable as I show below;

```
    +------+------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| name | date | CountedVOLUME | DailyVolume | adjusted_volume |
+------+------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
| A    |    1 |            10 |             |                 |
| A    |    1 |            11 |          21 |                 |
| A    |    2 |            12 |             |                 |
| A    |    2 |            13 |             |                 |
| A    |    2 |            14 |          39 |                 |
| A    |    3 |            15 |          15 |                 |
| A    |    4 |            16 |          16 |                 |
| A    |    5 |            17 |             |                 |
| A    |    5 |            18 |             |                 |
| A    |    5 |            19 |             |                 |
| A    |    5 |            20 |          74 |                 |
| A    |    6 |            21 | 0.127272727 |                 |
| A    |    6 |            22 |          43 |     0.133333333 |
| B    |    1 |            10 |             |                 |
| B    |    1 |            11 |          21 |                 |
| B    |    2 |            12 |             |                 |
| B    |    2 |            13 |             |                 |
| B    |    2 |            14 |          39 |                 |
| B    |    3 |            15 |          15 |                 |
| B    |    4 |            16 |          16 |                 |
| B    |    5 |            17 |             |                 |
| B    |    5 |            18 |             |                 |
| B    |    5 |            19 |             |                 |
| B    |    5 |            20 |          74 |                 |
| B    |    6 |            21 | 0.127272727 |                 |
| B    |    6 |            22 |          43 |     0.133333333 |
+------+------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Adjusted_volume = CountedVOLUME/ (Summation of DailyVolumes in five days before)

I use same number for A and B just for simplicity.

How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces exactly the sample result you listed. Since you said you wanted to compute `adjusted_volume`, I assumed `dailyVolume` is already present in your base dataset.

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm='|' missover;
input name $ date countedvolume dailyvolume;
datalines;
A|1|10
A|1|11|21
A|2|12
A|2|13
A|2|14|39
A|3|15|15
A|4|16|16
A|5|17
A|5|18
A|5|19
A|5|20|74
A|6|21|
A|6|22|43
B|1|10
B|1|11|21
B|2|12
B|2|13
B|2|14|39
B|3|15|15
B|4|16|16
B|5|17
B|5|18
B|5|19
B|5|20|74
B|6|21|
B|6|22|43
;
run;

data want (drop=cnt dv_:);
set have;
by name date;
retain dv_1 dv_2 dv_3 dv_4 cnt 0 dv_sum;
if first.name then do;
    cnt=0;
    dv_1=0;
    dv_2=0;
    dv_3=0;
    dv_4=0;
    dv_sum=0;
end;
adjusted_volume=countedvolume/dv_sum;
if last.date then do;
    cnt=cnt+1;
    if cnt=1 then dv_4=dailyvolume;
    else if cnt=2 then dv_3=dailyvolume;
    else if cnt=3 then dv_2=dailyvolume;
    else if cnt=4 then dv_1=dailyvolume;
    else do;
        dv_sum=dailyvolume+dv_1+dv_2+dv_3+dv_4;
        dv_4=dv_3;
        dv_3=dv_2;
        dv_2=dv_1;
        dv_1=dailyvolume;
    end;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Proc expand is what you're looking for. The worked example almost works. I'm sure you can tinker with the calculation to get exactly what you're looking for.

```
data begin;
    input name $ date CountedVOLUME @@;
    cards;
    A 1 10 A 1 11 A 2 12 A 2 13 A 2 14
    A 3 15 A 4 16 A 5 17 A 5 18 A 5 19 
    A 5 20 A 6 21 A 6 22 
    B 1 10 B 1 11 B 2 12 B 2 13 B 2 14 
    B 3 15 B 4 16 B 5 17 B 5 18 B 5 19 
    B 5 20 B 6 21 B 6 22 
    ;
run;


proc sort data=begin; by name date;

proc means data=begin noprint;
    by name date; 
    output out= daily
    vsum(CountedVOLUME) = dailyVolume
    ;
run;

proc expand data=daily out=expanded;
    by name;
    convert dailyVolume=movsum / transformout=(movsum 5);
run;

proc sort data = begin; by name date; run;
proc sort data = expanded; by name date; run;

data almost_wanted;
    merge begin(in=a) expanded(in=b);
    by name date; 
    if a and b;
run;

data wanted;
    set almost_wanted;
    adjusted_volume = CountedVOLUME / movsum;
run;
```

Comment: `proc expand` is a SAS/ETS procedure which the poster may not have.